# Should my / route redirect to /en/?

Tags: url, seo, url-routing

I'm working on a website with the url strategy that the site's locale is embedded in the url, eg.

```
example.com/en/    - Welcome page in English
example.com/en/... - English pages here
example.com/de/    - Welcome page in German
```

etc.

If the user opens the url http://example.com/ then the default (English) content should be shown. The question is, should I duplicate the content from http://example.com/en/ or should I redirect to that location?

I think that the user would find it more intuitive if he is not redirected away from the / route. But I have heard that search engines (mainly Google) does not like that multiple pages contain identical content, and will downgrade the page rank based on this.

Is this true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the best way is to redirect to that location. It isn't a good seo practice to have duplicate content on your website.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can get away without doing any redirection or duplicate contents if you save the chosen language in the client itself (i.e: cookie).

so by default, internally, you will show the english content. but if the user selects a different language, a cookie will be set in the browser and the next time, having this cookie you can now internally decide to show the content for another language.

EDIT: having different domain names might also help, like: en.example.com and es.example.com (this would allow google to index both of your sites)